# нужно разобраться со строкой

Tags: javascript, node.js

есть такой код

```
const canadianDollar = 0.91;

function roundTwo ( amount ) {
        return Math.round(amount * 100) / 100;
}
exports.canadianToUS = canadian => roundTwo(canadian * canadianDollar);
exports.USToCanadian = us => roundTwo(us / canadianDollar);
```

Как понять эту строку, как она читается и зачем тут canadian?

```
exports.canadianToUS = canadian => roundTwo(canadian * canadianDollar);
```

Comment: это функция а canadian параметр

Answer (score 0, accepted):

аналог

```
exports.canadianToUS = function(canadian) {
   return roundTwo(canadian * canadianDollar);
}
```